Error code on Renault Clio Expression 2014 Auto
I had a message pop up the other day on my Renault Clio Expression 2014 Dual Clutch Auto saying “check auto gearbox”. I took it to a European specialist who did a diagnostic tests on the gearbox to see if there was any issues with it. Everything came back fine that was working and no fault. Battery was checked too and it was good too. Any other suggestions as to what could’ve caused this fault? Can it sometimes happen when a window or something is left open? He did find that there wasn’t enough voltage reaching the gearbox which could’ve caused it and he reckons it may have been due to a window not closing properly which my passenger side window didn’t close properly at the time but now it’s fixed.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
